# Scala IDE problem loading Scala project with both java JRE 8, and JRE 11 installed (for java development on latest JRE)

Tags: java, scala, ide

Specifically on macOS, not verified on other platforms. Scala IDE had problem loading Scala project, when additional JRE-11 (in addition to JRE-8) was installed. Used switch to update JAVA_HOME pointing to JRE path. Verified java -version. Sounds like Scala IDE was not taking cue from JAVA_HOME environment setting. It would work only if JRE-11 was removed. Appreciate the help from anyone had this issue, and figured out the way to properly set it up. Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem? Do you have some log?

Comment: The problem was obviously because Scala IDE was trying to load JRE 13.0.1. Installed JREs:
[0] 11.0.5, x86_64: "Amazon Corretto 11" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home
[1] 1.8.0_231, x86_64: "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home
$JAVA_HOME is set to jdk1.8.0_231.jdk. 
java -version:
java version "1.8.0_231"
. . .
!SESSION 2019-10-30 10:11:33.806 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0-vfinal-2017-09-29T14:34:02Z-Typesafe
java.version=13.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
. . .